# Nav menus all outputting the same links

Tags: functions, theme-development, menus

I have registered the following menus in my functions.php

```
// register menus
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'footer-01' => 'Footer 01',
            'footer-02' => 'Footer 02',
            'footer-04' => 'Footer 04'
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_menus');
```

I've set them up with their each own set of links.

Now I've put the following into my theme files to show them on the pages:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'footer-01' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'footer-02' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'footer-04' ); ?>
```

But it seems that each menu outputs the same set of links, they all show the links that have been added to the `footer-04` menu

How do I get menus 01 and 02 to show their own links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have registered the following menus in my `functions.php`

Note that [`register_nav_menus()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/) which uses [`register_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/) (note the singular "menu") does not register or create a navigation menu; it only registers navigation menu **locations** which you can assign one or more (navigation) menus to, and for displaying the menus assigned to a specific location, you can use `wp_nav_menu()` just as you've already tried.

> How do I get menus 01 and 02 to show their own links?

The problem in your `wp_nav_menu()` call is because you're not specifying the proper navigation menu *location* which is identified by the `theme_location` parameter like so:

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=footer-01' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=footer-02' ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=footer-04' ); ?>
```

More details based on the [`wp_nav_menu()`'s reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#more-information):

> #### Usage
>
> `wp_nav_menu( $args );`
>
> **Given a `theme_location` parameter, the function displays the menu assigned to that location.** *If no such location exists or no menu is
> assigned to it, the parameter `fallback_cb` will determine what is
> displayed.*
>
> If not given a `theme_location` parameter, the function displays
>
> - the menu matching the ID, slug, or name given by the `menu` parameter; e.g. `wp_nav_menu( 'menu=123' )` or `wp_nav_menu( [ 'menu' => 'My Menu' ] )`
> - otherwise, the first non-empty menu;
> - otherwise (or if the menu given by `menu` is empty), output of the function given by the `fallback_cb` parameter
>   ([`wp_page_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/),
>   by default);
> - otherwise, nothing.

(Note: I slightly modified the above quote.)

So be sure to check the reference/docs and supply the proper function arguments. And remember that the above `$args` can be an array like `array( 'key' => 'value' )` (or `[ 'key' => 'value' ]`) or a query string like `key=value&key2=value+2`. Both will work in most cases, but when the value contains a space or the value is complex (e.g. it contains HTML tags), then you should use the *array* format. :)